# Can your iOS app be killed by the OS for high energy impact?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, instruments

I've got a difficult to fix bug. It's an exception bad access, that won't throw an all exception breakpoint. No stack trace is given. Turning zombies on isn't trigger any zombies, etc.

While memory usage is insignificant I notice that Energy Impact is quite high, both CPU and GPU.

Here's a screenshot of the usage.

[image]
Will the OS kill your app in this case, and not give much warning or information? Is there anything I can trip similar to `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning`?

Comment: I think the os may kill an application for any reason, but I don't think that is what's happening here. But I have very little apple experience.

Comment: Hi, A side question, but could you give me details of the iOS Version and XCode version you are using please?

Comment: @KarthikH iOS 10, Xcode 8.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Per Apple's guidelines here for [Performance Tips](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html), there is no indication that excessive power usage will result in your app being terminated.

The only reference to the OS taking action is located here:

> The power management system in iOS conserves power by shutting down
>   any hardware features that are not currently being used